# JSPM Angular2-rc2 build animate error

Tags: angular, jspm

So, building my angular2 project with JSPM for release: `jspm bundle-sfx app dist/main.sfx.js`. All fine, until I try to load the built app up in the browser. This is the error I get:`

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AnimationDriver! (ViewUtils -> RootRenderer -> DomRootRenderer -> AnimationDriver

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
```

Full log is as follows:

```
The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AnimationDriver! (ViewUtils -> RootRenderer -> DomRootRenderer -> AnimationDriver).
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AnimationDriver! (ViewUtils -> RootRenderer -> DomRootRenderer -> AnimationDriver).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
    at BrowserDomAdapter.supportsWebAnimation (browser_adapter.js:507)
    at _resolveDefaultAnimationDriver (browser.js:95)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (reflective_injector.js:468)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (reflective_injector.js:410)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._new (reflective_injector.js:399)
    at ReflectiveInjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (reflective_injector.js:275)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:571)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:548)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByReflectiveDependency (reflective_injector.js:539)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (reflective_injector.js:441)
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AnimationDriver! (ViewUtils -> RootRenderer -> DomRootRenderer -> AnimationDriver).
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AnimationDriver! (ViewUtils -> RootRenderer -> DomRootRenderer -> AnimationDriver).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
    at BrowserDomAdapter.supportsWebAnimation (browser_adapter.js:507)
    at _resolveDefaultAnimationDriver (browser.js:95)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (reflective_injector.js:468)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (reflective_injector.js:410)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._new (reflective_injector.js:399)
    at ReflectiveInjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (reflective_injector.js:275)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:571)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:548)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByReflectiveDependency (reflective_injector.js:539)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (reflective_injector.js:441)
InstantiationError {_wrapperMessage: "DI Exception", _originalException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
    at BrowserDomAdapter.supportsWebAnimation (htt…, _originalStack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null↵… (https://randohinn.com/w2w/main.sfx.js:47702:34)", _context: null, _wrapperStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at InstantiationError.Wrap… (https://randohinn.com/w2w/main.sfx.js:47702:34)"…}
```

What could cause such an error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same error when I have bundled angular2 app with webpack. It turned out that in my case it was complaining that `document.body` is `null`. This happens when you include your scripts in `head` before `body` section and script immediately trying to operate with `document.body`.

My index.html was like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="">

    <title>Legal Review</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <script src="build/thirdparty.js"></script>
    <script src="build/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app-component>
        Loading...
    </app-component>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I've moved scripts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="">

    <title>Legal Review</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <app-component>
        Loading...
    </app-component>

    <script src="build/thirdparty.js"></script>
    <script src="build/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me using JSPM bundle-sfx. There error message was pretty cryptic and I was basing my script tag location on the Angular2 docs quick-start example...

Comment: thanks a lot, I could not understant why this error looked random!